# How to Change Underlined Font Color in Android

Tags: java, android, html

I have a problem with the Font Color for the Website link in an Android App. Please see the code below:

```
 Email.setText(Html.fromHtml("W : "+"<u>" +Email1+ "</u>"));
```

Can i change the Font Color for **Underlined Email1 Text** without changing the **W :** Color?

Is there any HTML Tags can be used inside `"<u>" +Email1+ "</u>"` to change the Font Color. Please help me with your ideas/code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: avadhani did you get it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can dothis

```
Email.setText(Html.fromHtml("W : "+"<u><FONT COLOR=\"#80776b\" >"+Email1+"</Font></u>"));
```

Use color code what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Just because we can I added the 'manual' method to generate the exact same output using a `SpannableStringBuilder`:

```
String wText = "W : ";
String underlineText = "email@address.com";

SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
ssb.append(wText);
ssb.append(underlineText);
ssb.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), ssb.length()-underlineText.length(), ssb.length(), 
    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
ssb.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan("normal", android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium, 14, 
    ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED), ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED)),
    ssb.length()-underlineText.length(), ssb.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spannable_text1);
tv1.setText(ssb);

TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spannable_text2);
tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(wText + "<u><font color=\"#FF0000\">" + underlineText + "</font></u>"));
```

[image]

By the way, in stead of only underlining the email address, you could also make it a clickable link. Just so you know. :)

Answer (score 1):

use setTextColor tag to change the color of the text

eg:

```
Email.setTextColor(Color.RED);
         Email.setText(Html.fromHtml("W : "+"<u>" +"this is test"+ "</u>"));
```

Comment: And how would that prevent the "W : " substring from being set the same colour...?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this should work for you, You want like this?

```
    String styledText = "W: "+"<u>" + "<font color='red'>Email1</font> "+"</u>";
    Email.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest solution i guess...

```
Email.setText(Html.fromHtml("W : "+"<u  style=\"color:#80776b\">"+Email1+"</u>"));
```